# Connect-PnPOnline : Method not found when using it in Visual Studio Code, working fine in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am currently working on a PowerShell Code I can deploy in Azure-Functions, that creates a new SharePoint Site. I am working in Visual Studio Code.

Everything is working fine when doing it in PowerShell manually, but some commands don't seem to work in the Code. `New-PnPSite` throws:

> Exception: No connection, please connect first with Connect-PnPOnline

This Exception makes complete sense but when I use "Connect-PnPOnline" before using "New-PnPSite", I get:

> ERROR: Connect-PnPOnline : Method not found:
>   'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String, System.String)'.

I am not sure why it's not working, because my PowerShell and my Visual Studio Code PowerShell Code are using the same Module folder.
How do I get it to work in Visual Studio Code?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$env:PSModulePath` had the wrong path.